# Datatable javascript does'nt show icons on pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I'm working with the javascript datatable in rails.

I have a table that has icons in a column instead of words (when you click on actions).

My table:

```
<md-table-container>
  <table
    md-table id="table" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
    <thead
      md-head>
      <tr md-row>
        <th md-column>#</th>
        <% attributes.each do |attribute| %>
          <th md-column><%= attribute[:human_name] %></th>
        <% end %>
        <th md-column><%= t('actions', scope: :crud_views) %></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody
      md-body>
      <% records.each_with_index do |record, index| %>
      <tr md-row>
        <td md-cell><%= "#{index + 1}" %></td>

        <% attributes.each do |attribute| %>
          <td md-cell><%= record.send(attribute[:name]) %></td>
        <% end %>

        <td md-cell layout="row">
          <% if policy(record).show? %>
            <md-button
              href="<%= polymorphic_path(record) %>"
              class="md-small" >
              <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                <%= t('details', scope: :crud_views) %>
              </md-tooltip>
              <md-icon ng-md-icon icon="visibility" size="16"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
          <% end -%>

          <% if policy(record).edit? %>
            <md-button
              href="<%= polymorphic_path(record, action: 'edit') %>"
              class="md-small" >
              <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                <%= t('edit_resource', scope: :crud_views, resource: model.model_name.human) %>
              </md-tooltip>
              <md-icon ng-md-icon icon="mode_edit" size="16"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
          <% end -%>

          <% if policy(record).destroy? %>
            <md-button
              href="<%= polymorphic_path(record) %>"
              data-method="delete"
              data-title="<%= t('confirmation_required', scope: :crud_views) %>"
              data-confirm="<%= t('are_you_sure', scope: :crud_views) %>"
              class="md-small" >
              <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                <%= t('delete_resource', scope: :crud_views, resource: model.model_name.human) %>
              </md-tooltip>
              <md-icon ng-md-icon icon="delete" size="16"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
          <% end -%>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</md-table-container>
```

The important part:

```
<td md-cell layout="row">
          <% if policy(record).show? %>
            <md-button
              href="<%= polymorphic_path(record) %>"
              class="md-small" >
              <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                <%= t('details', scope: :crud_views) %>
              </md-tooltip>
              <md-icon ng-md-icon icon="visibility" size="16"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
          <% end -%>

          <% if policy(record).edit? %>
            <md-button
              href="<%= polymorphic_path(record, action: 'edit') %>"
              class="md-small" >
              <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                <%= t('edit_resource', scope: :crud_views, resource: model.model_name.human) %>
              </md-tooltip>
              <md-icon ng-md-icon icon="mode_edit" size="16"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
          <% end -%>

          <% if policy(record).destroy? %>
            <md-button
              href="<%= polymorphic_path(record) %>"
              data-method="delete"
              data-title="<%= t('confirmation_required', scope: :crud_views) %>"
              data-confirm="<%= t('are_you_sure', scope: :crud_views) %>"
              class="md-small" >
              <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                <%= t('delete_resource', scope: :crud_views, resource: model.model_name.human) %>
              </md-tooltip>
              <md-icon ng-md-icon icon="delete" size="16"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
          <% end -%>
        </td>
```

A row looks like this (See last column
):

[image: Row]

It looks perfect! just as I want it.

Problem: When advancing to the next page, icons are no longer displayed.

[image: Row 2]

The last column shows (in Spanish) the actions

```
Detalles = Eye
Editar Usuario = Edit icon
Eliminar Usuario = Delete icon
```

Second problem: words do not redirect to actions (I can not click "Details" or "Edit user").

So:

How is it possible to load the table correctly?
Other information: When doing a search, if it includes results of the next page, the icons are not shown either (It shows incorrectly)

EDIT:
SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable( {
      info: false,
      language: {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No hay información",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Ultimo",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                text: 'Exportar a Excel',
                filename: "Datos Exportados",
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: columns
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: 'Exportar a PDF',
                filename: "Datos Exportados",
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: columns
                }
            },
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: it's just a presumption, but maybe it is turbolinks...wich is the Ruby and the Rails version of your project?

Comment: If you are using Rails 5, try to replace `$(document).ready(function(){..` with `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){...`